# LINQ - get total count of values from nested list

Tags: c#, linq

i have a `Class`:

```
public class Company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public List<string> phones { get; set; }
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a `Generic List` which contains that `Class`:

`public List<Company> Companies = new List<Company>();`

i want to do two things:

1. get a distinct list of the categories
2. get a total count of companies per category

i think i managed to the the first thing:

`Companies.SelectMany(c => c.categories).Distinct()`
please tell me if you think anything is wrong with that.

i tried the second step as so:
`Companies.SelectMany(c => c.categories).Where(c=>c == Category).Count()`
but im not sure that is really right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Correct
2. You need to flatten the list into (company, category) pairs, then group by category:

   ```
   from company in Companies
   from category in company.Categories
   group company by category into g
   select new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
   ```

   ---

   **EDIT**: If you want to find out how many companies are in a single given category, you can write

   ```
   Companies.Count(c => c.Categories.Contains(categoryName))
   ```

Comment: a company can have more then 1 category, that is the count that i need, how many companys are under a specific category

Comment: it still gives me the same results as i wrote on Hasan's comment.

Comment: Then you're making a mistake.  Please show your code and data.

Answer (score 4):

```
Companies
    .SelectMany(c => c.categories)
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(g => new 
        {
            Cateogry = g.Key, 
            Count = g.Count()
        });
```

If you want it for specific category then your query is correct already.

Comment: @Dementic my answer gives you what you want. Try it out

Comment: well, since i need to specify the Category, i dont think it does.

Comment: @Dementic; your second query is also right if you want it for specific category

Comment: it dosent seem right, since from the data i have, there are 2109 companies, two categories (by the code above) and each category contains (3/7) companies,which is a total of 10, which is not right.

Comment: @Dementic then you might have duplicate entries of category in the same company. In which case you need to do .SelectMany(c=>c.categories.Distinct())

Comment: i think i dont explain my self good enough, since each company has at least 1 category, the total companies in categories should be the same. not the other way around.